# Localization $U^{-1} N$ where $U = R^{\times}$ is the set of nonzero elements of an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, localization

> Suppose $R$ is an integral domain with quotient field $Q$ and let $N$ be any $R$-module.  Let $U = R^{\times}$ be the set of nonzero elements in $R$ and define $U^{-1}N$ to be the set of equivalence classes of ordered pairs of elements $(u,n)$ with $u \in U$, $n \in N$, under the equivalence **$(u,n) \sim (u',n)$ if and only if $u'n = un'$ in $N$.**

I tried assuming they meant $(u,n') \sim (u',n)$.  I tried also assuming they meant $U = Q^{\times}$ instead of $R$.  Each time I was unable to prove transitivity.  So....?

Comment: My question is how to prove transitivity of the relation given ($\sim$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They meant $(u,n) \sim (u',n')$ if and only if $u'n = un'$ (the idea is that $(u,n)$ represents $\frac un$). To show transitivity, suppose $(u,n) \sim (u',n')$ and $(u',n') \sim (u'',n'')$. Then 
\begin{align*}
  u''nn' &= u''n'n\\
         &= u'n''n\\
         &= u'nn''\\
         &= un'n''\\
         &= un''n'
\end{align*}
As $R$ is an integral domain, $u''n = un''$, hence $(u,n) \sim (u'',n'')$.

Comment: How did you get the first equality?

Comment: Commutativity ... $R$ is an integral domain ...

Comment: Did you invert your notation from mine on purpose?

Comment: Okay, I get that $u' un'' = u' u''n$ (in my notation).  But how do you prove the rest knowing $R$ is ID?

Comment: As $R$ is an integral domain, $R$ does not have zero divisors, hence $ab = 0$ with $a \ne 0$ implies $b = 0$. Now use this for $u'(un'' - u''n) = 0$. *And*: I did not invert your notation, I corrected your correction: You corrected $(u',n) \sim (u,n)$ to $(u',n) \sim (u,n')$, but the correct thing is $(u',n') \sim (u,n)$. (Think of $(u,n)$ as $\frac un$).